# Split data set with multiple entries of same subject into train/val/test with predefined proportions and no same subjects in split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I've got a large dataset (Pandas DataFrame) that looks something like this (as an example, random numbers):

|  | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature 3 | Subject code | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -5.86 | 0.99 | 4.39 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 0.63 | 1.26 | 0.94 | 1 | A |
| 3 | 0.97 | -0.47 | 9.22 | 2 | A |
| 4 | 4.53 | 0.46 | -1.48 | 2 | B |
| 5 | 0.82 | 4.27 | -0.9 | 2 | C |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| X | 1.68 | 7.22 | 5.34 | 9419 | A |

Now, I want to split this data set into three groups for machine learning purposes: train, validation and test with certain sample proportions (e.g. 0.8, 0.1, 0.1). However, the data set I've got has multiple data points of the same subject ('Subject code'). I do not want entries of the same subject to be in more than a single split (train/val/test) at the same time, to prevent bias. My question is: how to do this? Is there a way to split a data set into three groups with the condition that the same subject code is only present in a single group? I've seen solutions that allow for splitting based on 'Subject code' with certain proportions only, but some subjects have many more data points than others, which would lead to different sample proportions.

Functions like `train_test_split` from scikit-learn don't seem to support adding such a condition to the split.

Many thanks!

EDIT: The subject code and the subject label will be removed from the data set after splitting. The subject code can be interpreted as someone's name (unique person identifier), the subject label is the target variable that I'm trying to predict with a model.

Comment: Wouldn't such approach cause more bias, what are you triyng to achieve with that form of data? Also, after the model creation stage, will the same subjects' labels are going to be predicted or will there be new subjects? If there will be newcomers, you wouldn't want to include `Subject Code`.

Comment: The subject code and the subject label will be removed from the data set during the model creation stage. The subject label will be the target (i.e. what I'm trying to predict) and the subject code is just an identifier for a person (like a name).

Eventually, I want to use unseen data (test) without the label/code to predict this label. But if the model has already seen some data subjects in the test set (with that code), it's biased and the test set performance would be inflated.

Comment: It would be incorrect to assume that the same person's data will cause bias in this example since data points and labels vary in each subject, it would require a thorough test for that hypothesis.

Comment: The data above is dummy data for the sake of an example/to explain the problem. In the actual data, multiple rows/data points of a single subject are strongly correlated as it's medical imaging data from a longitudinal study. The actual problem also isn't classification but a regression problem.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I do not think this would be the right way to go.
Should do you do so, you'll have an estimation of your model when tested **only on a subset of subjects**. That is, you have little or no clues on how your model generalizes to other subjects.
A better solution, in my opinion, would be to switch to a different validation method. In this case, [LeaveOneGroupOut](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut.html#sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut) or [GroupKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold) are valuable alternatives, depending on the size of your dataset.
The former trains a model on all subjects but one, and tests on the remaining subject, until all subjects are tested.
The latter splits the data in K non-overlapping folds such that a subject never appears in both train and test set. Then, it uses k-1 folds for training and 1 for testing, until all folds are tested.
Either way, you'll only have train and test sets (no validation set), but at the end it turns out to have a better overview on the generalization of your model.

Regarding the proportion of subjects, that is something that you have to handle in advance. Your dataset would be imbalanced either you use `train_test_split` or other validation methods. [Random oversampling](http://glemaitre.github.io/imbalanced-learn/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.html) or [Random undersampling](https://glemaitre.github.io/imbalanced-learn/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html) are two techniques you can start with, although more advanced exist.

As a final remark, your (example) dataset suggests that a given subject is observed across time. This put you in a context of time-series analysis. In this case, I suggest you to use a [*walk-forward validation*](https://medium.com/eatpredlove/time-series-cross-validation-a-walk-forward-approach-in-python-8534dd1db51a).
In walk-forward, the dataset represents a time series that can be divided into orderable parts, e.g., a datetime.
Such parts are chronologically ordered, and in each run, all data available before the part to predict is used as the train set, while the part to predict is used as test set, thus preventing the test set from having data antecedent to the train-set.
Afterward, the model performance is computed as the average among runs.
The number of iterations is equal to the number of parts minus one.
Specifically, you'd train each model on the first *n* dates (regardless of the fact that a subject occurs multiple times) and test on the *(n+1)*-th date.